# I am losing session data when being redirected from Payment GateWay using java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, session-variables, payment-gateway

I am setting some values using java session. After calling the Payment gateway, all me stored session values are losing. Please help me how to get those session values.

i set the some values to session like session.setAttribute("id", 120). After redirect the paymeny gateway. I try to get the id using session.getAttribute("id"). Here it returns the null value.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information. How are you initializing the session? Which payment gateway? Are session tokens URL parameters or cookies?

Comment: session variables ang payment gateway is www.CCAvenue.com

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Are session variables transmitted as URL parameters or cookies?

Comment: Sorry, before redirected to payment gateway, i set the some values to session like session.setAttribute("id", 120). After redirect the paymeny gateway. I try to get the id using session.getAttribute("id"). Here it returns the null value. Please help me.

Comment: Again, that is **not what I am asking**. Is the JSP session ID stored as a URL parameter, or a cookie?

Comment: i didnt get your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80883/discussion-between-chakri-and-hexafraction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From chat, you had stated that you are keeping the JSP session ID in a URL parameter rather than a cookie. This will cause an issue with the callback from the payment gateway, if the callback URL does not specify the same session ID.

This means that you need to put the session ID in the callback URL. I am not familiar with CCAvenue as a payment gateway, but I can tell you this much:

When you set the callback URL, you need to encode the session ID onto it using [`HttpServletResponse#encodeURL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29)

You would pass the URL of the callback (i.e. your homepage) to this method, and it will return the callback URL with the session ID encoded within it, *if necessary*. You can then use this URL as the user redirect (callback) on your gateway and when the redirect completes, the page will be loaded with a valid session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JSESSIONID in the callback url something like the following :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("someName", someObject);

String callbackURL = "http://yourapplicationserver.com/callback.jsp;JSESSIONID=" + session.getId();
String redirectURL = "http://paymentgateway.com/process?callbackURL=" + URLEncoder.encode(callbackURL, "UTF-8");

response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```